# elasticsearch does not take # tag into account

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I use elasticsearch plugin using aws lambda nodejs service:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/quick-start.html

And everything works fine.
I am new to it and still learning.'Here is my query:

```
        requestBody = elasticSearchBuilder.requestBodySearch()
        .query(
            elasticSearchBuilder.boolQuery()
                .must(elasticSearchBuilder.multiMatchQuery(fields, "#test")
                    .type(sortAlgorithm)
                    .tieBreaker(tieBreaker)
                    .minimumShouldMatch(searchAccuracySent))
                .must(elasticSearchBuilder.matchQuery("enabled", "1"))
                .filter(elasticSearchBuilder.rangeQuery(dateTimeFieldRangeCheck).gt(dateFrom))
                .filter(elasticSearchBuilder.rangeQuery(dateTimeFieldRangeCheck).lt(dateTo))
        ).sort(elasticSearchBuilder.sort(dateTimeFieldRangeCheck,"desc"))
```

The problem is no matter if I search for test or #test the above query returns only results related to test.
So apparently it does not take # into account.

I appreciate if anyone can help me

Update:

Here is my pure es query:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "#test",
                    "fields": [
                        "channel_name",
                        "owner",
                        "owner_channel",
                        "byline_name",
                        "byline_publication",
                        "headline",
                        "seo_terms",
                        "category",
                        "body",
                        "pull_quote"
                    ],
                    "type": "best_fields",
                    "tie_breaker": 0.3
                }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                    "enabled": "1"
                }
            }
        ],
        "filter": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "publish_datetime": {
                        "gt": "2013-02-28 23:59:16"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "range": {
                    "publish_datetime": {
                        "lt": "2020-02-28 23:59:16"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"sort": [
    {
        "publish_datetime": "desc"
    }
  ]
 }
```

Comment: Please add generated query instead of code in specific language. Also add the mapping of index to question. To get mapping use `GET /<index_name>/_mapping`

Comment: @NishantSaini Added :)

Comment: Have look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55180647/elastic-search-in-asp-net-using-ampersand-sign#55184445). This difference is only of character `&` instead of `#`, but solution and reasoning is same.