# Elastic Search in ASP.NET - using ampersand sign

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch, tokenize

I'm new to Elastic Search in ASP.NET, and I have a problem which I'm, so far, unable to resolve.

From documentation, I've seen that `&` sign is not listed as a special character. Yet, when I submit my search ampersand sign is fully ignored. For example if I search for `procter & gamble`, `&` sign is fully ignored. That makes quite a lot of problems for me, because I have companies that have names like `M&S`. When `&` sign is ignored, I get basically everything that has M or S in it. If I try with exact search (`M&S`), I have the same problem.

My code is:

```
void Connect()
{            
    node = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"]);
    settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
    settings.DefaultIndex(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaultIndex"]);
    settings.ThrowExceptions(true);
    client = new ElasticClient(settings);                        
}

private string escapeChars(string inStr) {
    var temp = inStr;
    temp = temp
        .Replace(@"\", @"\\")
        .Replace(@">",string.Empty)
        .Replace(@"<",string.Empty)
        .Replace(@"{",string.Empty)
        .Replace(@"}",string.Empty)
        .Replace(@"[",string.Empty)
        .Replace(@"]",string.Empty)
        .Replace(@"*",string.Empty)
        .Replace(@"?",string.Empty)
        .Replace(@":",string.Empty)
        .Replace(@"/",string.Empty);
    return temp;
}
```

And then inside one of my functions

```
Connect();    
ISearchResponse<ElasticSearch_Result> search_result;            
var QString = escapeChars(searchString);                  
search_result = client.Search<ElasticSearch_Result>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(101)
    .Query(q => 
        q.QueryString(b => 
            b.Query(QString)
            //.Analyzer("whitespace")
            .Fields(fs => fs.Field(f => f.CompanyName))                                
        )
    )
    .Highlight(h => h
        .Order("score")
        .TagsSchema("styled")
        .Fields(fs => fs
            .Field(f => f.CompanyName)
        )
    )
);
```

I've tried including analyzers, but then I've found out that they change the way tokenizers `split` words. I haven't been able to implement changes to the tokenizer.

I would like to be able to have following scenario:

Search: `M&S Company Foo Bar`

Tokens: `M&S` `Company` `Foo` `Bar` + bonus is if it's possible to have `M` `S` tokens too

I'm using elastic search V5.0.

Any help is more than welcome. Including better documentation than the one found here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/5.x/writing-queries.html.

Comment: Have you tried to escape the `&` with a \?

Comment: @MarvinKlar yes, I've tried changing & with \&, "&", etc. None of it worked. And reserved characters are: + - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ / https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html. So single & sign shouldn't be the problem in the first place

Comment: I think the elasticsearch query is performed through an web request. So maybe the `&` is wrongly interpreted by the url. Maybe using the unicode char works (`&#38;` or `&#x26;` or `&amp;`).

Comment: I have initially tried changing & with &#x26; which gave no results. I've tried now with other 2 suggestions you recommended, and neither gave result. Regardless of the way I send & sign, highlights in my results never include & sign at all. Which suggest me that somewhere, in some of the settings, & sign is ignored (even though it is not listed as a reserved character in the list I've sent above)

Comment: Sorry, I was braindead. When you want to escape the `&` char in theu rl you have to use `%26`. But I guess, that this woun't give any better results...

Comment: Nope, I've tried that too already :). The only difference was that it didn't even look for anything after the sign. For example in the "procter&gamble" search, I only had "procter" highlighted, which means that "gamble" haven't been searched for.

Comment: This seems to be happening because of the analyser applied on the field. Please  add mapping of index to get a better insight.

Comment: Note that analyzer is commented out. It's not being applied. Index mapping is whatever is the default.

Answer (score 2):

By default for a text field the analyzer applied is [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/analysis-standard-analyzer.html). This analyzer applies [standard tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) along with [lowercase token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html). So when you are indexing some value against that field, the standard analyzer is applied on that value and the resultant tokens are indexed against the field.

Let's understand this by e.g. For the field `companyName` (text type) let us assume that the value being passed is `M&S Company Foo Bar` while indexing a document. The resultant tokens for this value after the application of standard analyzer will be:

```
m
s
company
foo
bar
```

What you can notice is that not just whitespace but also `&` is used as delimiter to split and generate the tokens.

When you query against this field and don't pass any analyzer in the search query, it by default apply the same analyzer for search as well which is applied for indexing against the field. Therefore, if you search for `M&S` it get tokenised to `M` and `S` and thus actual search query search for these two tokens instead of `M&S`.

To solve this, you need to change the analyzer for the field `companyName`. Instead of standard analyzer you can create a custom analyzer which use [whitespace tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html) and lowercase filter (to make search case insensitive). For this you need to change the setting and mapping as below:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "whitespace_lowercase": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "companyName": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "whitespace_lowercase",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now for the above input the tokens generated will be:

```
m&s
company
foo
bar
```

This will ensure that when searching for `M&S`,  `&` is not ignored.

Comment: Would you be able to help with the changes in the code? I have tried un-commenting analyzer and changing it to "whitespace_lowercase", but it throws me an error, and I don't have an option to change tokenizer, filter or mappings. That is - I don't know where to insert that in my previously listed code